# Когда стоит напрямую использовать ThreadPool в c#?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

В [документации Microsoft на ThreadPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=net-7.0) есть такая фраза:

*При создании Task объекта или Task для асинхронного выполнения некоторых задач задача по умолчанию планируется для выполнения в потоке пула потоков*

В таком случае возникает вопрос: а стоит ли, вообще, использовать пул потоков напрямую, через вызов **ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc);** или нет? Если да, то в каких случаях это стоит делать?

Comment: Нет, не стоит. Использование Тасков намного проще. Единственное исключение: если приходится по каким-то причинам писать под старую версию FW, где ещё нет Task. В этом случае остаётся только посочувствовать.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot Раздумываю. Мне нужно обрабатывать файлы в пакетном режиме. Кроме того, нужно на форму вернуть результат обработки файла: обработан или нет. Видимо, всё-таки есть смысл использовать ThreadPool.

Comment: Ок, удалил ответ как бесполезный